# работа с SqlDataAdapter в C#

Tags: c#, sql

```
string  command ="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + name_table;
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command, sqlConnection);
DataSet max = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(max);
int count = max.Tables[0];
```

Подскажите как вывести результат запроса при использовании adapter

Answer (score 0):

Адаптер используется для заполнения `DataTable` данными. Между тем у вас запрашивается *одно* значение: `COUNT(*)`. Следовательно, нужно читать одно значение:

```
string command = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + name_table;
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"..."))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(command, conn))
    {
        int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        Console.WriteLine(count);
    }
}
```